# Laravel form not getting any data on redirect (no errors no input)

Tags: php, validation, laravel-4

I have a form for creating an organization. If I do not pass the name of the organization through, it fails validation as it should. In the store method I can see the proper errors in $this->validator->getErrors() and I pass those in, but NOTHING shows up in the form. I can dump errors and Input:old() from the view form yet nothing is there. What am I missing?

```
public function create()
{
    $supportedStates = ['' => 'Choose'] + $this->us_states->supportedStates();
    $procedures = $this->procedures->getList();
    $phoneTypes = $this->phone_types->lists('phone_number_type', 'id');
    return View::make('organizations.create', array('supportedStates' => $supportedStates, 'procedures' => $procedures, 'phoneTypes' => $phoneTypes, 'input' => Input::old()));
}

public function store()
{
    $input = Input::all();
    if($this->validator->passes())
    {
        $new_organization = $this->repository->create(['organization_name' => $input['organization_name']]);  
        if($input['logo_url'])
        {
            $new_organization->processImage($input, Request::root());             
        }
        $new_organization->createRelated($input);
        return Redirect::route('/')
            ->with('message', 'Organization Created.');
    }

    return Redirect::route('organizations.create')
        ->withInput()
        ->withErrors($this->validator->getErrors())
        ->with('message', 'There were validation errors.');
}
```

Comment: Where is the form template?

Comment: The form template is in the view for Organizations

Comment: I am dumping variables from the form view and no old input or errors are showing up ($errors is empty).

Answer (score 0):

You need to show us how you are displaying the errors on ther form.
Are you using the below to get the errors

The errors are in messages.

```
//send this to your view from controller
$messages = $validator->messages();

//retrieve errors in view
foreach ($messages as $message)
{
    //
}
```

Comment: If I dye and dump right before I return the redirect after the validation fails I get the following for    $this->validator->getErrors() "object(Illuminate\Support\MessageBag)#619 (2) { ["messages":protected]=> array(1) { ["organization_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(40) "The organization name field is required." } } ["format":protected]=> string(8) ":message” }
". If I try Session::all() I get array(1) { ["_token"]=> string(40) "dkAdwXBo5uvsaSGo5mhLL3RJmjyEUT21WNm3pvsG” }  Session::get('error') returns NULL.

Comment: It's clear that the errors are in messages. $messages = $validator->messages();foreach ($messages->all() as $message)
{
    //
} see my edited answer above

Comment: No, I look for $errors or $input. $messages is not set as a variable.

Comment: Yes I'm suggesting you can set $messages or $errors as a variable by assigning it to $validator->messages(). Also how are you showing the old input: {{Input::old('input_name')}} ? And is organizations.create a route name?

Comment: As I understand L4, when I redirect using withErrors or withInput, that sends $errors and $input to the redirected view. Yes, organizations.create is a route name.